# Select if all fields are different from

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

I have the next query to select the convocations whose date is minor or equal to `$date` and (province code is 08, 25, 17 or 43 OR **ALL `proposal.type`'s are different from `simple_majority`**). The next query (I think) will select **if one type is different**, because there are some proposals that belong to the same convocation.

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT c FROM RedconviveConvocationBundle:Convocation c
            INNER JOIN RedconviveConvocationBundle:Community co ON co.id = c.community_id
            INNER JOIN RedconviveConvocationBundle:Proposal p ON p.convocation_id = c.id
            WHERE c.date <= :date AND (co.provice_code = 08 OR co.provice_code = 25 OR co.provice_code = 17 OR co.provice_code = 43 OR p.type != simple_majority")
        ->setParameters(array('date' => $date))
        ->execute();
```

How to select only if ALL PROPOSALS FROM CONVOCATION are not equal to `simple_majority`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        "SELECT c FROM RedconviveConvocationBundle:Convocation c
        INNER JOIN RedconviveConvocationBundle:Community co ON co.id = c.community_id
        INNER JOIN RedconviveConvocationBundle:Proposal p ON p.convocation_id = c.id
        WHERE c.date <= :date AND (co.provice_code = 08 OR co.provice_code = 25 OR co.provice_code = 17 OR co.provice_code = 43) AND p.type != simple_majority")
    ->setParameters(array('date' => $date))
    ->execute();
```